# Certs-Buzz and Magento Certified Developer Exam Training Material

Tags: magento2, database, critical

I'm attempting to take the test for the Magento Certified Developer.

I wonder if the appropriate responses given to each address are dependable?

Since when I resulted in these present circumstances question today,

For an attribute to be loaded on a catalog/product object, which two of the following conditions
must be satisfied? (Choose two)
A. The eav_attribute table must contain a row defining the attribute's properties and its entity type.

B. The attribute must have a backend model configured in the XML config.

C. The attribute must be part of the attribute set pertaining to the object being loaded.

D. There must be a record of the attribute on the catalog_product_super_atti:ibute table.

E. There must be a column added to the catalog_product_entity table.

Answer: A , C

I am little Bit Confused Can I Someone tell about A , C

Source Link: https://www.certsbuzz.com/magento-certified-developer-questions-bank

Comment: Yes, Its right answer to A and C

Answer (score 0):

A says that the attribute must exist in the database.

C says that the attribute must be part of the product's attribute set.